# How to open gallery instead of camera in phone gap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

This is my code but its not working properly why?????

```
    $("body").on('click', '#capture_image2', function(event)
    {
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(imageCaptureSuccess, imageCaptureError,
        { limit: 1,  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY } );

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to follow the instructions given in [Phonegap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

With **capureImage** function, you are accessing to the camera application for taking images, instead of this you should use the **getPicture** function with the correct *sourceType* to get a picture from your gallery.

Specifically, this function will open your Gallery and handle the process

```
function getPhoto() {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
}
```

Note:
In **Android**, SAVEDPHOTOALBUM and PHOTOLIBRARY are the same for picture sourceType, if not provided, sourceType is Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA by default, which leads your app to retrieve the picture from Camera.